# How to get first 4 digits from an integer in PHP

Tags: php, integer

After a few calculations I get:

```
$int = 14.285714285714;
```

How can I take only the first four digits? Expected output: `14.28`

Comment: You need to round it with precision 2? If the integer is 123.45 what do you want to take? Please be more specific and add more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **substr** function

```
$int = 14.285714285714;
echo substr($int, 0, 5);

$newint = (float)substr($int, 0, 5);
```

---

IF you want to round the number you can use

```
round($int, 2);
```

> **OUTPUT WILL BE : 14.29**
>
> ---
>
> [LINK HOW TO ROUND](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Comment: really casting to an int?

Comment: Really, don't accept this, it's the wrong way to round a number.

Comment: he dont want to round the number ... he want first 4 digit of the number @Synchro

Answer (score 2):

Doing this with string functions is absolutely the wrong way to go about this, and these nearly identical answers look pretty spammy. If you want to round a number, round a number!

```php
$int = round(14.285714285714, 2);
```

To truncate (as opposed to rounding), `floor` is the correct function in PHP:

```php
$int = floor(14.285714285714 * 100) / 100;
```

Both work without any type conversions or casting.

Also note that a number with decimal places is categorically not an integer.

Comment: He dont want to round he want first 4 digit -1

Comment: I just did this on the cmd line and I get `14.29`.  The OP wants `14.28`.

Comment: @Joshua Huber look at my answer

Comment: Ha ha, we were writing the same idea at the same time using `floor`. I got downvoted for it by some silent downvoter.  Beware.

Answer (score 1):

Try number format,

```
string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] )
```

so

```
$int = 14.285714285714;
$small = (float)number_format (  $int ,2,'.', '' ); //gets rid of the "," for thousand separator
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Really a down vote for using number format to format a number, what's it for then?

Comment: `number_format` is for formatting a number for display, not for rounding. Your example will produce the wrong answer if it's used in calculations.

Comment: Where does to Op say it's used for calculations? it says "Expected output:", not to mention you can simply cast it to a float.

Comment: Agree the downvoting is out of hand.  Gave you +1 for the viable solution using number_format. We have to supply assumptions since the original question was vague.

Comment: Dito on that, I just like number format because it gives you the option to change the decimal and thousand separator.  Generally If I was doing calculations on it I would only round the results I display because that would be far more accurate for floats.  Rounding it before calculating it you could be +/- 1 off.

Answer (score 0):

`floor(100 * 14.285714285714) / 100`

14.28

Comment: Ok, silent downvoter, speak up. What's the problem? This code returns the OP's desired output, 14.28.

Comment: "When should I vote down?
Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." - http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down